# How to perform Survival Analysis on Engine Breakdown data?

Tags: probability, survival, hazard

I have this problem. I am doing a university project that is about estimating a time to breakdown of a bus engine. I believe that Survival Analysis is the approach that I should use, but have some doubts since I am very new with this problematic. I have data of ALL engine breakdowns of entire bus fleet of Public Transportation company for the past 10 years. The fleet consists of approximately 1000 buses, and in the past 10 years, each bus occurred in Breakdown 1 time (max 2 in individual cases).

Would someone provide me with some advice on how to start building the analysis with this kind of data? At the end, of course, I expect to have a probability of a breakdown occurring in some particular time frame.